# Error in parseInt line

Tags: java, android, textview

So, I'm having this android math game of mine. And I'm having a hard time figuring out why is it that I got these errors and trying out some codes found on the internet but It's not working.

My code here below has no errors. But when I try to run it, I'm having errors in my logcat.

```
 check.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        int x = Integer.valueOf(fn.getText().toString());
        int y = Integer.valueOf(sn.getText().toString());

        public void onClick(View v){
         String ope = op.getText().toString();


         if(ope=="+"){
             if(x + y == total2){
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Answer is correct. You may proceed to level 2.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
         }

         if(ope=="-"){
             if(x-y==total2){
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Answer is correct. You may proceed to level 2.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
         }  


         if(ope=="*"){
             if(x*y==total2){
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Answer is correct. You may proceed to level 2.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
         }

         if(ope=="/"){
             if(x/y==total2){
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Answer is correct. You may proceed to level 2.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
             else if(y/x==total2){
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Answer is correct. You may proceed to level 2.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }

         }


         }});
```

and here's my LOGCAT:

[image]

I'm parsing it right, right? So, why I'm having these errors?

**Note:** fn and sn are textViews, and the op as well. fn and sn are where the users put their operands answers and the op is the operator. The game has this random number given and the user should tap 2 operands and an operator to make an equation and able to come up with the random number given. Result of her/his equation should be same as the random number given.

Thankyou :)

Comment: what view element is fn in you code?

Comment: ok try this: int x = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(fn.getText()));

Comment: Already tried this plus @Henry's comment below, it worked but still got errors although my answer is correct.

Comment: @pingboo23 Please don't add SOLVED to the title. Mark the answer that worked with the green checkmark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems in your code. First as Henry mentioned in your answer that  you need to put these lines:

```
  int x = Integer.valueOf(fn.getText().toString());
  int y = Integer.valueOf(sn.getText().toString());
```

inside of the `onClick` method

Second problem is that you are using `==` to do the string comparison in all of your `if` checks, such as:

```
     if(ope=="+")
```

You should use String `equals()` method to do the string comparison. Change it and other if conditions to use equals method, as mentioned here:

```
     if(ope.equals("+"))
```

`==` compares whether the two references are pointing to the same memory location, while `equals()` does the string content comparison.

Comment: @pingboo23 This is because you have space in your string ' 16'. Use trim method as specified here   int x = Integer.valueOf(fn.getText().toString().trim());  int y = Integer.valueOf(sn.getText().toString().trim());

Comment: I just removed any other spaces and it works fine, no need to trim it. By the way, already voted it up :)

Comment: @pingboo23 you just upvoted and not marked it. There is a difference between these two thi

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you get the `x` and `y` values when you attach the onClick listener. The fields are still empty at that time.

To fix that put these lines

```
    int x = Integer.valueOf(fn.getText().toString());
    int y = Integer.valueOf(sn.getText().toString());
```

inside of the `onClick` method.

Comment: I tried it, and works okay at first. But when I try to click the check button, it says, "FORCE CLOSE". Although my answer is correct. It should print that My answer is correct.

Comment: What is the exception in logcat?

Comment: @pingboo23 check my answer, it tells you why you see force close